# How much (clean-looking) drywall should be removed around moldy studs?

Tags: drywall, mold, flooding

I had a pipe in the attic burst during a freeze last December. I was out of town, so water ran down from the attic for at least a day before I got to it. The flow rate wasn't high; I had turned off the main valve before leaving--still not sure where the water was coming from.

I can get by without using that part of the house, so after fixing the pipe and tearing up the flooring to let it dry, I didn't address the interior of the wall where the water came down for a few months, although I did run a dehumidifier quite a bit. Now I've been in the process of removing the drywall, and I'm finding some dry mold on the drywall and studs.

Since I've already opened this part of the wall, it seems prudent to remove the mold I can see. What I'm unsure about is how much more drywall to remove. Referring to the attached pictures, there's mold visible on the studs, but the drywall from the other side of the wall doesn't look bad. It's possible though that it could be moldy in the areas I can't see, where it makes contact with the studs. I'd really like to not remove more drywall than necessary, but at the same time, while I've got the wall open, I may as well address the important parts.

In an area like this, where the mold is dry and unlikely to get wet again, how bad would it be if there is mold on the backsides of those studs that doesn't get removed? Thanks in advance for any advice you can give me.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Dried mold can come back to life if any moisture/humidly touches it.  Best thing is to spray down with a mold killer, like bleach.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for your response. I intend to remove the visible mold, but my uncertainty is more about if it's necessary to remove the remaining drywall. It doesn't look bad to me, but there could possibly be mold on the stud faces that I can't see because they're up against the drywall.

Comment: Spraying down with a mold killer should work.  The seams between drywall and studs are not well sealed so the killer should soak in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. Spray it with the stuff.